# ui_orientation, one more undocumented pearl from Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I saw this ui_orientation candy on a WWDC video, used on this context

```
UIImage *finalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg
                      scale:2.0f orientation:ui_orientation([displayImage properties])];
```

apparently it reads the orientation of the CCImage to create the UIImage properly, but using this on my code produces this error: **implicit declaration of function 'ui_orientation' is invalid in C99**

Do you guys know what header should I include on my source to make this function work?

thanks.

NOTE: WWDC 2012 - lesson 510 at 25'16" ... when the UIImage is created

Comment: Are you sure it's an undocumented function? I doubt it be one. Maybe just some quickly-whipped-up macro that's defined in that particular piece of sample code? Also, if you expect it to be one, then why do you think there's a (public) header file which contains it?

Comment: if it is on a WWDC video as a code sample showing how developers should do something, it is public.

Comment: Could you provide some more context, like which video you saw this in?

Comment: WWDC 2012 - lesson 510 at 25'16" ... when the UIImage is created.

Comment: Since it's not in any public header, I agree with @H2CO3 and I believe that's just a commodity function/macro defined in that specific demo.

Comment: It seems very likely that this function doesn't actually exist (or only exists as a one-off macro in some unpublished sample code). There's no reference to it anywhere else and given that the next slide shows a much shorter way of doing the same thing, perhaps the code on this slide was intended to just illustrate the general principle and not actually to be used – even the first line (`[CIContext context]`) wouldn't compile as it is.

Comment: @everybody I suggest somebody less sleepy/less lazy than me `otool -tv | grep ui_orientation` the UIKit executable.

Comment: @omz I found the place it's defined with Spotlight & WWDC PDFs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from Session 422, where they give the code

> Convert the orientation property to UIImageOrientation:

```
UIImageOrientation ui_orientation (NSDictionary* props)
{
    int o = [[props valueForKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyOrientation] intValue];
    UIImageOrientation map[] = {
        UIImageOrientationUp,
        UIImageOrientationUp, UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,
        UIImageOrientationDown, UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,
        UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored, UIImageOrientationRight,
        UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, UIImageOrientationLeft,
    };
    return map[o];
}
```

**Here's a handy tip too:** Download all the PDFs from all the WWDC sessions and keep them on your hard drive. They don't take up much space. That way when you want to find what session talks about `CATransaction` or (like here) a made up function, you can use Spotlight to find the PDF, which has the session number as its title.

Comment: fantastic. I have accepted this as an answer. The big question is if this works, I mean, if the CIImage orientation is really inside this mysterious "properties" that is apparently a NULL NSDictionary (yes I have tried to NSLog that) and is not documented either. And also on that video the guy mentions a sample code from that filter example app that is not on the WWDC2012 sample. Anyway, your answer was fantastic.

Comment: Very nice, hadn't thought of searching the PDFs. @RubberDuck The `properties` dictionary is documented a little bit in the `CIImage` header. If it's `nil`, the `ui_orientation` function would return `UIImageOrientationUp`.

Answer (score 3):

Following H2CO3's suggestion, I ran

```
otool -tv UIKit | grep ui_orientation
```

where `UIKit`'s path is

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework
```

The command returned no results, therefore I can confirm that there's no public definition of the function `ui_orientation`, as for iOS SDK 6.1.

That was probably a macro defined for the sake of that specific example, so shame on Apple for not making it clear.

Comment: I think at some point we all get used to Apple's crappy documentation but this frame at 25'16" at lesson 510, WWDC 2012 video took the prize. A single frame has a macro definition that is not mentioned, a line of code that does not compile and a [displayImage properties] that compiles in which "properties" is not in the docs and if you try to NSLog that (it appears to be a NSDictionary) it gives you null! hahaha... fantastic. This is what I call a tutorial.

Comment: that tutorial may have some issues, but if you consider Apple's doc crappy, I can't imagine an adjective bad enough to describe anybody else's docs.

Comment: Apple don't have docs, they have a bunch of stuff piled together. Once in a while they produce a bigger document that is better written, but 90% of their documentation is a pile of crap. The problem is that they hire geeks to write their docs. Geeks know how to do it and don't care to explain that to mere mortals. They should hire people who have didactics, like book authors.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Apple's doc is one of the best doc I've ever run into. I hope you never find yourself in the situation where you have to dig Android's docs.

Comment: I have learned all my programming using books. Switching from a well written book to what Apple produces is a shock. Well written books have examples after every API or they explain the API. Try to create a video capturing application just using AVFoundation framework reference. Good luck.

Comment: This is just another example of a crappy doc written by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html, simply because it is wrong. Static libraries cannot carry resources like images on iOS, as far as I have tried and all people on the web says. You have to create a bundle and add the resources to it. The worst thing of these crappy docs is that they are not typos are conceptual errors.